# How to display groups in Doddle Report?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting

I have downloaded the sample app of the Doddle Report and understand it is to report a collection of IEnumerable data. I am able to get data reported nicely for a simple report.

However, the sample app did not have grouping.  I would think to accomplish this I need to extend the functionality from the source code to show group format and wonder if anyone tried and succeed. If so, how should I approach it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Doddle Report doesn't have grouping capability built into the system.
According to some of the discussion on the codeplex,

[DoddleReport.Codeplex.com](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/discussions/256060)

it appears that the creator is also looking for someone to include that functionality.

One work-around I used for different groups was to create an excel report and then use `AppendReport()` to get multiple pages in the same report. Unfortunately, the iTextSharp report writer doesn't implement `AppendReport()` so I had to use the OpenXml writer for this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use OpenXml writer to AppendReport. This solves Excel format report.  Does this mean that we cannot create grouping in PDF format?

Comment: Thanks for that link! After the semester ends, I'll see if I can't get a pull request for the nuget package. Would love to have that in there.